# Using Flower with Azure Service Bus broker on python celery?

Tags: python, celery, azureservicebus, flower

Is Flower compatible with Azure Service Bus broker on celery to monitor tasks? I tried to launch the Flower service using

```
celery --broker "azureservicebus://RootManageSharedAccessKey:{key}@{asb-namespace}
```

However I am receiving an error:

```
 <Error><Code>404</Code><Detail>No service is hosted at the specified address. TrackingId:...
```

Although I am pretty sure the connection string should be correct. Searching for information for compatibility of brokers I found this doc page: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html

However, it only includes a subset (I assume) of brokers and does not mention Azure Service Bus. I assume it is not compatible but I wanted to make sure.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure as well, but I suggest you run `pip freeze` after installing `flower` to see if there are any `azure` packages installed.. (on an empty environment of course)

Comment: By default, flower does not install any azure packages (especifically, azure-servicebus package) but I needed to install it as it complains when trying to connect to the queue. Flower connects to it but it shows those "No service is hosted..." errors